# Weird symbols on end when inserting text into a file

Tags: c, fseek

I'm trying to make a simple program for inserting some text on specific position in existing text file. For example if is in file text.txt text "sample text", after running program should be in text.txt "saminserting textple text". But sometimes program inserts some Weird symbols to the end of text, so in this case I got "saminserting textple textX€" (where is for some reason "X€" on the end of text) and I can't figure out, why.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

FILE *file;

 file = fopen("text.txt", "rb+"); //processed file
 if (file == NULL) return 0;

 char *test = "inserting text"; //text for inserting
 char *buffer;
 int size;

 fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
 size = ftell(file);

 fseek(file, 3L, SEEK_SET);
 buffer = malloc(abs(3L - size) + 1);
 fread(buffer, abs(3L - size), 1, file);

 fseek(file, 3L, SEEK_SET);
 fwrite(test, strlen(test), 1, file);
 fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, file);

 free(buffer);
 fclose(file);

 return 0;
}
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why not `size -3` rather `abs(3L - size)` ?

Comment: Is `buffer` nul-terminated?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, well, only if the file contans a null-terminated string. which is most unlikely.

Comment: @Roddy i talk about `buffer`, not file. also file is text file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. Exactly: buffer never gets a null written to it. It's just filled from the file. (and while it's very unlikely, a text file could contain nulls...)

Comment: @Roddy _in file text.txt text "sample text"_ where ?

Comment: @Roddy It seems to be a troublesome if it must be assumed NUL is included in the position of any of the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buffer = malloc(abs(3L - size) + 1);
fread(buffer, abs(3L - size), 1, file);
...
fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, file);
```

You never null-terminate `buffer` so you potentially write a different about to what you read. Do this instead. (But really, use `size-3` or something nicer...)

```
fwrite(buffer, abs(3L - size), 1, file);
```